# Delete data from postgres/mysql on regular interval

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, rdbms

I have a spring boot app where I am using mysql or postgres database (based on client requirement).
In database I have a table in which I have to store data for 3 months. The data gets populated in this table continuously through a kafka stream. So I have a scheduled spring task defines that runs a query on a regular interval to delete.

```
delete from table where creation_time < (current_time - 3 months)
```

But when this table has a lot of data this query takes a lot of time and gets stuck sometimes. What is the standard way to define a ttl on table data or mass delete it once it gets old?

PS: I have an index on creation_time and my primary key is of type uuid.

Answer (score 0):

These scenarios should be handled **at DB level and not application level**.

Please consider defining an **Archival Policy** for your table to archive the old records.

Take a look here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/02/19/archiving-mysql-tables-in-clickhouse/

Comment: Can I consider moving all my data to clickhouse? Are there any downsides to it compared to using mysql?